# Formula in excel to count back 14 days & show following monday, but count back only 7 days if date entered is a monday

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I need to be able to enter a date that will count back 14 days and show the next Monday e.g. enter 25/12/2015 and get a return of 15/12/2015, however at the same time if I enter a date that happens to be a Monday it will only count back 7 days e.g. enter 15/12/2015 and get 08/12/2015 February. Tried using this formula but anytime i enter a date that is a Sunday it skips forward to the upcoming Monday...!!??!

=IF(WEEKDAY(D4)<2,D4+2-WEEKDAY(D4),D4+2-7-WEEKDAY(D4))

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

This works too. The problem is that Sunday has a lower weekday value than Monday. Mod 7 solves that problem.

=(D4-7)-MOD(WEEKDAY(D4)-2,7)

Comment: You can do this without MOD if you "offset" the date, e.g. `=D4-6-WEEKDAY(D4-1)`

Answer (score 0):

You mean the Monday 14th December Monday 7th December right?

`=CEILING(IF(WEEKDAY(D4,3)=0,D4-7,D4-14)-2,7)+2`

As a breakdown - I used Jon von der Heydens formula here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/468174-formula-find-next-monday.html.

`=CEILING(A1-2,7)+2` returns the following Monday date to the date in A1.
So using IF and the WEEKDAY formula: if the date is a Monday remove 7 days, otherwise remove 14 days and find the following Monday to that date.

Comment: Spot on kId, great help